# Can't get server validations to work using AngularJS and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, validation

I was trying to use [this approach](http://codetunes.com/2013/server-form-validation-with-angular/) to get it done but my app won't display error messages.

Here's my guest_controller.rb

```
def create
  guest = Guest.new(guest_params)
  if guest.save
    render json: guest
  else
    render json: {errors: guest.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Angular directive:

```
angular.module('HotelApp').directive 'serverError', ->
  restrict: 'A'
  require: '?ngModel'
  link: (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) ->
    element.on 'change keyup', ->
      scope.$apply ->
        ctrl.$setValidity 'server', true
```

Angular controller:

```
angular.module('HotelApp').controller 'GuestsCtrl', ($scope, Guest, guests, Address, addresses) ->

  $scope.guests = guests.data
  $scope.addresses = addresses.data

  $scope.save = (guest) ->
    $scope.errors = {} # clean up server errors

    success = (result) ->
      guest.id = result.data.id
      guest._new = false
    error = (result) ->
      # server will return something like:
      # { errors: { username: ["Must be unique"] } }
      angular.forEach result.data.errors, (field, errors) ->
        # tell the form that field is invalid
        $scope.guestForm[field].$setValidity('server', false)
        # keep the error messages from the server
        $scope.errors[field] = errors.join(', ')

    Guest.create(guest).then(success, error)

  $scope.new = ->
    $scope.guests.push { first_name: '', last_name: '', pesel: '', phone: '', email: '', _new: true }
```

and finally my template:

```
form name='guestForm' ng-submit="save(guest)" novalidate=true

  input ng-model='guest.pesel' placeholder='Pesel' type='text' name='pesel' ng-minlength='11' ng-maxlength='11' ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" class='form-control' server-error=true
  p ng-show='guestForm.pesel.$error.server' class='text-danger'
    | {{ errors.pesel }}
  p ng-show='guestForm.pesel.$error.pattern' class='text-danger'
    | Only digits.
  p ng-show='guestForm.pesel.$error.minlength' class='text-danger'
    | Too short.
  p ng-show='guestForm.pesel.$error.maxlength' class='text-danger'
    | Too long.
  button type='submit' class='btn btn-default' ng- disabled='guestForm.$invalid'
    | Save
```

Other validations works fine because they are made on the client-side but the server-error is not. Am I missing something here? After hit Save button the Chrome console gives the unprocessable_entity error and

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pesel' of undefined
    at guests_controller.js?body=1:14
```

which is

```
$scope.guestForm[field].$setValidity('server', false);
```